# Convert pdf to png, size issue

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, png, poppler

I have a pdf file created from an impress presentation. I want to convert the pdf to png images to add them to create a video using them. I am using pdftoppm to convert the pdf to png, but the exported images are getting a size of 1654x931 px. I need 1920x1080, as my video is going to be in that resolution.

The command I am using is the following:

```
pdftoppm -png report.pdf report
```

In Impress I haven't found any setting the set the size of the exported pdf, and I haven't been able to find anything to set the size of the png conversion.

Is there anyway to adjust the size of the generated pngs?

Comment: Does your version of pdftoppm not have a `-scale-to` option?

Comment: actually, that worked fine. I had to use scale-to-y andscale-to-x. If you post it as an answer, I would mark as the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks - I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdftoppm` appears to provide the following scaling options:

> ```
>    -scale-to number
>           Scales  the  long  side of each page (width for landscape pages,
>           height for portrait pages) to fit in scale-to pixels.  The  size
>           of  the short side will be determined by the aspect ratio of the
>           page.
>
>    -scale-to-x number
>           Scales each page horizontally to fit in  scale-to-x  pixels.  If
>           scale-to-y  is  set  to -1, the vertical size will determined by
>           the aspect ratio of the page.
>
>    -scale-to-y number
>           Scales each page vertically to  fit  in  scale-to-y  pixels.  If
>           scale-to-x  is set to -1, the horizontal size will determined by
>           the aspect ratio of the page.
> ```

Since 1654x931 and 1920x1080 have essentially the same aspect 16:9 ratio, it may be sufficient to use `-scale-to` to set the long edge to 1920 pixels:

```
pdftoppm -png -scale-to 1920 report.pdf report
```

Otherwise, you can set the x and y dimensions explicitly

```
pdftoppm -png -scale-to-x 1920 -scale-to-y 1080 report.pdf report
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with *.cbr / *.cbz, but it seems you'll have to combine two steps:

Convert PDF to Images

Compress them into a ZIP / RAR archive.

Regarding step 1, you could use ImageMagick's convert command. You can feed convert with a PDf comprising multiple pages, and convert will return each page as single graphics file. I've tested it with a text scanned at 400 dpi, and the following command resulted in nice single JPGEs:

**$ convert -verbose -colorspace RGB -interlace none -density 400 -quality 100 yourPdfFile.pdf 00%d.jpeg**

(credits regarding the -quality option: this forum entry)

As a result, you get 000.jpeg, 001.jpeg and so on. Just zip them into a .cbz file, and you're done.

You could even combine both steps by "concatenating" them:

**$ convert -verbose -colorspace RGB -interlace none -density 400 -quality 100 yourPdfFile.pdf 00%d.jpg && zip -vm comic.cbz *.jpg**

(make sure that there aren't any other JPEGs in your current working directory, since using the code above, zip will move all JPEGs into the cbz file)

Comment: OP didn't mention `*.cbr` or `*.cbz` files. Wrong question?